# Setting up a test machine

Tags: testing

I'm looking to set up an improved test environment. I use VMWare to easily set up a clean environment (fresh installation). This works OK for WinXP and simple tests, but our software is very memory and CPU intensive and VMWare is just too slow with Win7 & a full functionality test.

So I'd like to set up a system with a big hard disk that I can store disk images to. I've tried Clonezilla but it's quite cumbersome to use. I'm looking for a solution where I can boot from a usb drive which will then show me a list of the following:

- make new image
- restore image

and 'restore image' should give me a list with the available images (win xp, win vista, win 7, win 7 with office installed, etc) So basically just like VMWare, but non-virtualized.

I would think this would be something obvious, but for the life of me I can't find any software that advertises it can do this. 10 years ago, Norton Ghost could do something like this but I don't remember how easy it was to use, and anyway it seems that current versions focus more on being an end-user backup tool.

So, any advice on what is the best way to set up such a test environment? Any specific disk imaging software that works well, or other tips on how to set this up? Thanks.

Comment: I find VirtualBox to be very snappy. Win7 32bit host, allocated 4 cores to VM.

Answer (score 0):

**ISO Buster** might help you to put mirror images to set your required Environment.

You might want to take a look at it :

- http://get2pc.com/isobuster%202.8o36c-1-w-0-0
- http://www.isobuster.com/help.php?help=285[link text](http://www.isobuster.com/help.php?help=285)
- http://download.cnet.com/IsoBuster/3000-2248_4-10208087.html

Good Luck !